# Intermittently frozen screen

Tags: freeze, wayland

My screen freezes for a few seconds to a few minutes up to a few times per minute but the system is not frozen. Spotify will continue to play, VLC sound will continue to play, Youtube sound in Firefox or Chrome will continue. It appears that mouse clicks or Page Up/Down keyboard commands will stack up and execute as soon as the screen starts moving again. Mute keyboard command will not execute until the screen starts moving again.

If I log out and log back in or reboot, the freezes will go away for a while but they eventually come back and get worse until I have to log out again.

I have tried System Monitor and TOP but I don't see any obvious causes. Error logs don't show anything obvious to an idiot (me - but I really am an idiot here). I don't know how to troubleshoot this any further.

This problem has been occurring for more than a year but different versions of Ubuntu are better or worse. 21.04 was very good (I could live with it) but 21.10 is really bad (I can't live with it). I don't remember what version of Ubuntu started it (2019?). Same PC since 2017. Same functional configuration HTPC since 2010.

Other freezes searched do not seem to be the same problem. Their solutions did not help.

Dual boot to Win10 with no issues there.

- CPU - AMD A8-7600 w Radeon R7
- MOBO - ASROCK fm2a88m pro 3+
- RAM - 2 x 8 GB
- SSD partition - 270 GB - 130 GB free

What can I do to troubleshoot this further?

edit 2022/01/04:
Yesterday while I was writing this post, screen freezes where constantly interrupting me. Today when I ran the below commands, screen freezes were nearly nonexistent. Some days have always been better than others. I did perform an Update/Upgrade and a reboot this morning but I do not think my problem has resolved until I experience a longer period without screen freezes.

I will also try a live USB suggested below when I get the chance.

```
ed@ed-htpc:~$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
P2.60
ed@ed-htpc:~$ free -h 
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            13Gi       3.1Gi       1.6Gi        97Mi       8.9Gi        10Gi
Swap:          2.0Gi       1.0Mi       2.0Gi
ed@ed-htpc:~$ sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60
ed@ed-htpc:~$ swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile                               file        2097148 1792    -2
```

Also, this HTPC records television from a network attached TV tuner (MythTV <-> HDHomerun) and the recorded video file shows no interruptions if the screen freezes during a background recording. MythTV will also continue to play sound while the screen is frozen during video playback.

edit 2022/01/07: Increasing swap to 4 GB did not fix problem

```
ed@ed-htpc:~$ free -h
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            13Gi       4.4Gi       620Mi       166Mi       8.6Gi       8.7Gi
Swap:          4.0Gi       244Mi       3.8Gi
```

edit 2022/01/12: Tests run so far seem to rule out hardware  problems. I do not know how to troubleshoot this further. I have looked in the Logs app but I do not know how to recognize a significant message. I should wait until the freezes become a major disruption and then look at some kind of log but I don't know what.  (or look at logs for 2021/01/03 - that day was very heavy)

edit 2022/05/28: A few weeks ago I broke down and fresh installed 22.04. The frozen screen problem immediately happened before installing any additional software. Some reading caused me to try something I have never tried over the past few years because I was unaware it was possible.

I logged out of Wayland and logged in with XORG.

The problem has gone away (or changed to something I can live with). Very occasionally, screen updates (like dragging a window) are slow or jumpy but cursor response is always immediate. If I log out and log back in, screen updates are restored to immediate. If I log out of XORG and log in with Wayland, the intermittent screen freezes return.

I do not blame this problem on hardware because dual booting to Win10 does not have any issues. Wayland appears to be my problem. It is possible that my intermittent problem over the past few years has been directly coincident with the advent of Wayland in Ubuntu. XORG may not be a complete solution but it is for now satisfactory. (it still appears that maybe my video response degrades over time and is restored by logging out)

I am still willing to take action on troubleshooting suggestions but my video problems have receded to an occasional minor inconvenience.

Comment: If you have a bit of time and a Live USB nearby, one option would be to boot into a live session and see if the system continues to have issues when playing videos or doing simple things. If there are no issues with the Live USB session, then there's a potential configuration issue. If the problem continues, then a deeper investigation of drivers and log files will be necessary 

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `swapon -s`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, you can either do a bug report or go back to 20.04 LTS for steady operation, other half-year span release is more like a testing purpose.

Comment: @heynnema requested data added above.

Comment: @EdMcGuirk Please see my answer. If it helps to solve the problem, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**BIOS**

ASROCK FM2A88M Pro3+

Your BIOS is the most current, at 2.60.

**SWAP**

Let's increase your /swapfile from 2G to 4G and see if that solves the problem.

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `rm` and `dd` commands can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 16G RAM and 4G swap
```

Edit /etc/fstab, using `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`.

Confirm this /swapfile line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines... use SPACES in this line... confirm NO TABS...

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

**MEMTEST**

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take a few hours to complete.

Comment: increasing swap to 4 GB  did not fix problem. I will try to remember to run memtest overnight. (New 'free -h' results added above)

Comment: @EdMcGuirk Thanks for the update! Let me know how `memtest` goes. If it freezes, then it may point to bad memory.

Comment: I think it might have frozen. I will attempt several more overnight runs of memtest including removal of each 8 GB memory stick and maybe different allocations of video memory from RAM.

Comment: @EdMcGuirk Thanks for the update! Keep me posted.

Comment: It took 10 hours but memtest completed without errors. I am a little confused by RAM dedicated to graphics. Memtest shows 14 GB RAM whether 0 or 2 GB is dedicated to graphics and it appears like memtest freezes if 2 GB is dedicated to graphics. I need to test again with dedicated graphics RAM to prove memtest freeze.  So, I still do not know what is causing Ubuntu freeze.

Comment: @EdMcGuirk If `memtest` freezes, no matter how much graphics memory is configured, then it's not a Ubuntu problem, but a hardware problem. You were going to pull out a 8G DIMM at a time and test with the remaining 8G, and then test with the other DIMM by itself... what happened with that?

Comment: I did not test 8 GB with one stick removed because the test passed with 16 GB. My first test had 2 GB RAM allocated to graphics and it looked frozen but I was unfamiliar with the program and I may not have read the screen correctly. The second test was with graphics RAM disabled and passed with zero errors after 10 hours. I have since tested that disabling graphics RAM will leave the previous RAM allocation. That explains memtest showing 14 GB of 16 GB available for testing. I have reduced graphics RAM allocation to the minimum of 32 MB and disabled graphics. I will test full 16 GB overnight.

Comment: @EdMcGuirk Thanks for the update.

Comment: Which would be more valuable: testing 16 GB with 32 MB graphics deactivated or testing 14 GB with 2 GB graphics activated? I'll do both but each one will be more than 10 hours for 4 passes of all tests so it will be two overnight tests.

Comment: @EdMcGuirk 16G with minimal shared graphics memory.

Comment: Test passed for 16 GB with zero errors. It took 11.5 hours. I will modify future tests for only 3 passes. I will test again with graphics RAM allocation 2 GB activated. I doubt this is a hardware problem.

Comment: @EdMcGuirk You don't need to run `memtest` again. On your normal boot, do you have the latest Radeon drivers installed? Do you know how to boot from the GRUB menu with nomodeset?

Comment: I am not using any proprietary drivers and none show as available. I don't know how to use nomodeset but a quick search implies it only affects boot before X is loaded?

Comment: @EdMcGuirk At the GRUB menu, hit "e" to enter edit mode. Use the arrow keys to find "quiet splash" and change it to "quiet splash nomodeset", then control-x or F10 to continue booting. This will only prove if there's a problem with the Radeon or its driver. Screen resolutions may be off, and the Display Settings may not fully function, until reboot. See if the freezing stops.

Comment: Normally the freezing only starts after many hours of run time. 6, 12, or more than 24 hours before the first freeze then usually getting worse until a reboot or logout/login is required. Some days are better then others.

Comment: @EdMcGuirk And increasing the /swapfile didn't help this freezing? Monitor `free -h` and keep an eye on swap/used. Did you do the nomodeset?

Comment: Increasing swap did not fix problem. Freezing has only been light/moderate all week (reboot a day keeps freezing away) even before increasing swap to 4 GB but swap/used has never been worse than a few hundred MB (currently 1 MB).  I will try nomodeset later this afternoon. All tests that require a reboot delay heavy freezing.

Comment: nomodeset set the resolution to a nearly unusable 800x600 and no sound through the HDMI port with no options to change. I can't use that for hours waiting for freeze to come back. I didn't see any freezing but I would not normally see any in the first few minutes anyway.

Comment: @EdMcGuirk Don't know what to say then. Sorry.